# Capturing Form Data in Java Servlet - Code hunting as well

Tags: java, servlets

I would like some feedback on a particular problem that I am trying to understand. I am trying to build a simple Java web app that will allow a user to enter their zipcode and a distance, and have a java servlet capture that data and run it through Best Buy's API, BBYOpen, to return the locations of the stores closest to the information provided. The Remix.Java API (Provided by BBYOpen) documentation offer this as an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.mattwilliamsnyc.service.remix.*;

public class RemixAdvancedDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Remix remix = new Remix("YourApiKey");

        List<String> storeFilters   = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> productFilters = new ArrayList<String>();

        storeFilters.add("area(11201,10)");
        productFilters.add("sku=8982988");

        try {
            StoresResponse response = remix.getStoreAvailability(
                storeFilters,
                productFilters
            );

            if(!response.isError()) {
                for(Store store : response.list()) {
                    System.out.println(
                        store.getName() + " (" + store.getDistance() + " miles)"
                    );
                    for(Product product : store.getProducts()) {
                        if(product.hasInStoreAvailability()) {
                            System.out.println(product.getName());
                            System.out.println(
                                "Available for $" + product.getSalePrice()
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else {
                ErrorDocument error = response.getError();
                if(null != error) {
                    System.out.println(error.getStatus());
                    System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Examples:");
                    for(String example : error.getExamples()) {
                        System.out.println(example);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(RemixException e) {
            e.printBackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example to find stores in New York City the have Playstation 3's available. Which is not what I am looking to do. But I think that what I need is in here somewhere with a little tinkering.

1.I am assuming that I can remove any references to **products** in the code.

2.Do I need the List storeFilters = new ArrayList();? Is this necessary to the servlet.

3.Can I use getParameter() to retrieve the user input from my .jsp form, and then reference it in the storeFilters.add("area(11201,10)"); replacing the values already in there.

I am quite new to java, and any help or advice on this would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It does seem that you can ignore the parts of the example that deal with products since you are only interested in locations.
2. That line is declaring the variable **storeFilters** and initializing it as an empty list. So yes that part is required, since you are adding filters to that list later on in the code. Check out the documentation on List (and ArrayList): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html
3. Yes, HttpServletRequest.getParameter() will give you the string values of form fields (and querystring parameters) so you can dynamically create the filter you need and add it to the storeFilters list.